# How to show 5 users with highest rating? django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to show the 5 users with the highest rating. However, they currently don't appear ordered and when I add two ratings to a user it appears twice instead of calculating the average and putting in the right spot.

These are the models:

```
# this is model for user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    profilepic = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Uncomment if you don't want the slug to change every time the name changes
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

# this is the model for user ratings - one to many relationship with User
class UserRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.rating)
```

This is the view:

```
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.select_related().annotate(rating=Avg('userrating__rating')).order_by('-userrating')[:5]    
    city_list = City.objects.order_by('name')[:5]

    context_dict = {"users": user_list, "cities" : city_list}

    return render(request, "index.html", context_dict)
```

This is how refer to it in the template:

```
 {% for user in users %}
{{ user.rating }}
```

This is the result on the page -> unordered and repeated:

> Super Stars
>
> nikkityler Nikki Tyler from Glasgow, Scotland, 50.0
>
> nikkityler Nikki Tyler from Glasgow, Scotland, 100.0
>
> darrenhart Darren Hart from Munich, Germany, 0.0
>
> darrenhart Darren Hart from Munich, Germany, 35.0
>
> bunnyschultz Bunny from Madrid, Spain, 5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're ordering by the `userrating` instead of your annotation

```
user_list = User.objects.select_related().annotate(rating=Avg('userrating__rating')).order_by('-rating')[:5]
```

Also note that `user` is already defined by a Django context processor so you may want to give a different template variable in your loop

```
{% for my_user in users %}    
    {{ my_user.rating }}
```